# this is the last time I lend you money

Tags: grammar

> This is the last time I *lend* you money. I won't lend you again.

I don't understand the tense in the sentence above. Why does the present simple *I lend* work? I can understand why we can use the future tense (I'll lend) or the present continuous (I'm lending), but the present simple is odd to me.

Comment: I won't lend you any money again. Or : I won't do this again.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is correct, taking, "This," meaning at the *present time*, is when the money is being lent.

It would also be colloquially and grammatically correct to say, "This will be the last time I lend you money," if the money has not yet changed hands.

However, the second sentence is *not* grammatically correct; a preposition is missing.

Comment: Why does the present simple tense *I lend* work? Present simple expresses habitual action or permanent state.

Comment: @Stephen, present tense is used to describe something **currently happening**, not necessarily a permanent state. e.g., "I lend you this money now," or, "As I see the accident, I stop the car."

Comment: @Stephen You still have to learn about the present simple, this [graphic](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-simple-use.html) might help you. See: "we can  use the present simple for short actions that are happening now." Obviously in the case you are describing "It's the last time I'm lending you money" would also work. The difference in meaning here very very small.  Present simple focuses on the money lending, present continuous focuses more on the subject.

Comment: Thank you all very much.